# Prolog - count repetitions in list

Tags: list, prolog

I'm trying to look through a list and count the number of times a given word appears. I've got this so far:

```
count_repetitions([_], [], 0).
count_repetitions([Word], [Word|Tail], Count):-
   count_repetitions([Word], Tail, X), 
   Count is X + 1.
count_repetitions([Word], [Z|Tail], Count):-
   Word \= Z, 
   count_repetitions([Word], Tail, Count).
```

So the query `?- count_repetitions([yes],[yes,and,yes,and,no], X).` would give `X = 2`.

This appears to work. Now I need to write a predicate that outputs a list with the search word and the number of times it appears, in the form `X = [(yes - 2)]`. I'm completely stuck, any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are there, already, it seems to me. You could simply wrap your predicate in another one saying:

```
word_repetitions(Word, List, [(Word-Count)]) :-
    count_repetitions(Word, List, Count).
```

Note that you don't need the parenthesis or the brackets around the `Word-Count` pair:

```
word_repetitions(Word, List, Word-Count) :-
    count_repetitions(Word, List, Count).
```

(but you can use them if you insist).

On your original predicate, renamed to reflect the differences:

```
list_word_reps([], Word, Word-0).
list_word_reps([W|Rest], Word, Word-Reps) :-
    list_word_reps(Rest, Word, Word-Reps0),
    (   W == Word
    ->  Reps is Reps0 + 1
    ;   Reps = Reps0
    ).

?- list_word_reps([yes,no,yes,no,maybe,yes], yes, X).
X = yes-3.
```

The reason why the list comes before the word is that the predicate then becomes deterministic. Same goes for using the if-then-else instead of two different clauses. You can put the answer in a list if you want to (just wrap the argument in brackets) but again, it is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for your solution Boris. Having the X = [yes - 2] was a bit of a typo on my part, it needn't be in brackets. Thanks again!

Answer (score 8):

This answer shows a **logically pure** way to do it. The following is based on [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd).

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

We define [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate) `tcount/3` similarly to [`tfilter/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22053194/4609915)!

```
:- meta_predicate tcount(2,?,?).
tcount(P_2,Xs,N) :-
   N #>= 0,
   list_pred_tcount_(Xs,P_2,0,N).

:- meta_predicate list_pred_tcount_(?,2,?,?).
list_pred_tcount_([]    , _ ,N ,N).
list_pred_tcount_([X|Xs],P_2,N0,N) :-
   if_(call(P_2,X), (N1 is N0+1, N1 #=< N), N1 = N0),
   list_pred_tcount_(Xs,P_2,N1,N).
```

Now let's use `tcount/3` in combination with [`(=)/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29432897/4609915):

```
?- tcount(=(yes),[yes,and,yes,and,no],Count).
Count = 2.
```

Unlike the code presented by *all* other answers to this question,  the code presented in this answer is **monotone** and remains logically sound even when using it with non-ground terms:

```
?- tcount(=(yes),[A,B,C,D],2).
      A=yes ,     B=yes , dif(C,yes), dif(D,yes)
;     A=yes , dif(B,yes),     C=yes , dif(D,yes)
;     A=yes , dif(B,yes), dif(C,yes),     D=yes
; dif(A,yes),     B=yes ,     C=yes , dif(D,yes)
; dif(A,yes),     B=yes , dif(C,yes),     D=yes
; dif(A,yes), dif(B,yes),     C=yes ,     D=yes
; false.
```

Let's try something even more general:

```
?- tcount(=(yes),[A,B,C,D],Count).
      A=yes ,     B=yes ,     C=yes ,     D=yes , Count = 4
;     A=yes ,     B=yes ,     C=yes , dif(D,yes), Count = 3
;     A=yes ,     B=yes , dif(C,yes),     D=yes , Count = 3
;     A=yes ,     B=yes , dif(C,yes), dif(D,yes), Count = 2
;     A=yes , dif(B,yes),     C=yes ,     D=yes , Count = 3
;     A=yes , dif(B,yes),     C=yes , dif(D,yes), Count = 2
;     A=yes , dif(B,yes), dif(C,yes),     D=yes , Count = 2
;     A=yes , dif(B,yes), dif(C,yes), dif(D,yes), Count = 1
; dif(A,yes),     B=yes ,     C=yes ,     D=yes , Count = 3
; dif(A,yes),     B=yes ,     C=yes , dif(D,yes), Count = 2
; dif(A,yes),     B=yes , dif(C,yes),     D=yes , Count = 2
; dif(A,yes),     B=yes , dif(C,yes), dif(D,yes), Count = 1
; dif(A,yes), dif(B,yes),     C=yes ,     D=yes , Count = 2
; dif(A,yes), dif(B,yes),     C=yes , dif(D,yes), Count = 1
; dif(A,yes), dif(B,yes), dif(C,yes),     D=yes , Count = 1
; dif(A,yes), dif(B,yes), dif(C,yes), dif(D,yes), Count = 0.
```

What about the following corner case?

```
?- tcount(_,_,-1).
false.
```

And how about utilizing `tcount/3` as an alternative to `length/2`?

```
?- N in 1..3, length(Xs,N).
  N = 1, Xs = [_A]
; N = 2, Xs = [_A,_B]
; N = 3, Xs = [_A,_B,_C]
...                                      % does not terminate

?- use_module(library(lambda)).
true.

?- N in 1..3, tcount(\_^ =(true),Xs,N).
  N = 1, Xs = [_A]
; N = 2, Xs = [_A,_B]
; N = 3, Xs = [_A,_B,_C]
; false.                                 % terminates universally
```

Comment: Nice generalization, but the name. OK, it's about a noble count. Probably [Count von Count](https://www.google.com/search?q=count+count).

Comment: Minor ditch: `tcount(Pred_1, List, Count) :- list_pred_tcount(List, Pred_1, Count).` would be better on a WAM. And then, your counting could be improved by counting from 0 on!

Comment: Further ditch: `tcount(P_1, List, -1)` - should this really call `call(P_1,X)` at all?

Comment: @false: Guess the German name for "the count"... "Graf Zahl":)

Comment: Gróf Szám vs. Grófság

Comment: There is an error! It should be `:- meta_predicate tcount(2,?,?).`

Comment: @false. Thx 4 poing that out! Should be better now.

Comment: Bad for the nontermination of `N in 1..3, length(Xs,N).`.  This is due to length/2 proposing larger and larger N but the constraint on the N prohibiting failing any attempt at instantiation past 3. There should be something in the constraint to tell length/2 that it will never find a solution that way.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer. I agree. There should. No program should depend on the non-termination of  `N in 1..3, length(_,N), false`, so changing that behaviour is okay with me. But it also is somewhat ad-hoc-y, so the message it communicates is unclear. Right now, it's clear that old-school Prolog code like `library(lists)` behaves in this simple, but predictable way when used with finite-domain constraints. But what would reasonable expectations be with the extended `library(lists_X)` ?

Answer (score 2):

library(aggregate) is often undervalued:

```
count(L, C) :-
    aggregate(set(W-N), aggregate(count, member(W, L), N), C).
```

yields

```
1 ?- count([a,b,a],C).
C = [a-2, b-1].
```

so, the simpler

```
count(W, L, W-N) :-
    aggregate(count, member(W, L), N).
```

yields

```
?- count(a, [a,b,a], C).
C = a-2.
```

being based on setof, aggregate/3 allows for finer control about the quantification of variables (i.e. which values get aggregated), but will fail if there is no solution, instead of yielding 0, as sometime is required.

aggregate_all/3, based on findall/3, would return 0 in such cases, but doesn't allows for quantification specifiers.