# Write a recursive Prolog predicate of three arguments, called common, which returns the number of elements that belong to both lists

Tags: prolog

Write a recursive Prolog predicate of three arguments, called common, which returns the number of elements that belong to both lists.
       For example:

```
   ?- common ( [a, b, c, k, h], [b,c,d,e], N).
   N=2.

   ?- common ( [b, a, c, d], [a, b, c, d, e] ,  N).
   N=4.
```

Comment: //shoudnot use cut operation to intersect

Comment: Please show what you've tried in attempt to solving this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Preserve [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity)!

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

First, we define [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  `tcountd/3` in order to discount duplicate list items. 
`tcount/3` is similar to [`tcount/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29960878/4609915), but uses [`tfilter/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29963476/4609915) and [`dif/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29867514/4609915) for excluding duplicates:

```
:- meta_predicate tcountd(2,?,?).
tcountd(P_2,List,Count) :-
   list_tcountd_pred(List,Count,P_2).

:- meta_predicate list_tcountd_pred(?,?,2).
list_tcountd_pred([]     ,0, _ ).
list_tcountd_pred([X|Xs0],N,P_2) :-
   if_(call(P_2,X), (N #= N0+1, N0 #>= 0), N = N0),
   tfilter(dif(X),Xs0,Xs),
   list_tcountd_pred(Xs,N0,P_2).
```

We define `common/3` based upon [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  `tcountd/3`, [Prolog lambdas](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord), and  [`memberd_t/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29963476/4609915):

```
common(Xs,Ys,N) :-
   tcountd(Ys+\X^memberd_t(X,Ys),Xs,N).
```

Let's run the sample queries the OP gave:

```
?- common([a,b,c,k,h],[b,c,d,e],N).
N = 2.

?- common([b,a,c,d],[a,b,c,d,e],N).
N = 4.
```

As `common/3` is *monotone*, we get **sound answers** with non-ground queries, too! Consider:

```
?- common([A,B],[X,Y],N).
  N = 1,     A=B ,                         B=X
; N = 2,               A=X ,                         B=Y , dif(X,Y)
; N = 1,               A=X ,           dif(B,X), dif(B,Y)
; N = 1,     A=B ,                                   B=Y , dif(X,Y)
; N = 2,                         A=Y ,     B=X ,           dif(X,Y)
; N = 1,                         A=Y , dif(B,X), dif(B,Y), dif(X,Y)
; N = 0,     A=B ,                     dif(B,X), dif(B,Y)
; N = 1,           dif(A,X), dif(A,Y),     B=X
; N = 1,           dif(A,X), dif(A,Y),               B=Y , dif(X,Y)
; N = 0, dif(A,B), dif(A,X), dif(A,Y), dif(B,X), dif(B,Y).
```

Answer (score 0):

Trivially to do using `intersection/3` built-in:

```
common(A, B, N) :-
    intersection(A, B, C),
    length(C, N).
```

Test run:

```
?- common([a, b, c, k, h], [b,c,d,e], N).
N = 2.

?- common([b, a, c, d], [a, b, c, d, e],  N).
N = 4.
```

Notice that there is no space between "common" and "(" in the queries. This is important. Queries as you stated in the question (with space between "common" and "(") will give syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way, assuming you want to ensure that the result is a *set* (unique items) rather than a *bag* (allows duplicate items) :

```
set_intersection( Xs, Ys, Zs ) :- % to compute the set intersection,
   sort(Xs,X1) ,                  % - sort the 1st set, removing duplicates (so that it's a *set* rather than a *bag* ) ,
   sort(Ys,Y1) ,                  % - sort the 2nd set, removing duplicates (so that it's a *set* rather than a *bag* ) ,
   common( Xs , Ys , Zs )         % - merge the two now-ordered sets, keeping only the common items
   .

common( Xs , Ys , [] ) :-
  ( Xs=[] ; Ys=[] ) ,
  ! . 
common( [X|Xs] , [X|Ys] , [X|Zs] ) :-
  common( Xs , Ys , Zs ) .
```

Another, simpler way:

```
set_intersection( Xs , Ys , Zs ) :-
  set_of(Z,(member(Z,Xs),member(Z,Ys)),Zs)
  .
```

Another way:

```
set_intersection( Xs , Ys , Zs ) :-       % compute the set intersection by
  set_intersectin( Xs , Ys , [] , Zs ) .  % invoking the worker predicate

set_intersection( []     , _  , Zs , Zs ) .  % when we run out of Xs, we're done.
set_intersection( [X|Xs] , Ys , Ts , Zs ) :- % otherwise,
  member(X,Ys) ,                             % if X is a member of Ys,
  \+ member(X,Ts) ,                          % and we don't yet have an X,
  set_intersection( Xs , Ys , [X|Ts] , Zs )  % add X to the accumulator and recurse down
  .                                          %
```