# Searching a list for (same) two elements in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, prolog-dif

How can I search a list in Prolog for a specific element that appears more than once?

For example, if we are searching the list `[1,2,3,4,1]` for the element `1`, Prolog should return `true`, but otherwise `false` for all other numbers.

This is what I have so far:

```
duplicate([], _) :-
   false,
   !.
duplicate([X|_], X) :-
   true,
   !.
duplicate([H|T], X) :-
   T = [_|T1],
   duplicate(T, X),
   duplicate(T1, X).
```

My basic idea is to search the list until I find the element I am looking for, then search the tail of the list for the item again. I do not want to use the member() function provided by Prolog.

Prolog should also return the elements that appear more than once if asked by the query: `duplicate([1,2,3,4,1], X)`, should print `X = 1`.

Comment: You need to find an element X which is at least in two different places in L, nth0/3 is your friend !

Answer (score 3):

What I was saying in my comment was : I want two items from the list L wich are not in the same place so

```
duplicate(L, V) :-

   % nth0 gives the index (from 0) of an element in a list
   % element V is at the place Id1 in L
   nth0(Id1, L, V),
   % element V is at the place Id2 in L
   nth0(Id2, L, V),
   % Id1 is different from Id2
   % It is more usefull to say that Id1 < Id2
   % Thanks **false** for the improvement
   Id1 < Id2.
```

Another way to do this is to say : I remove the element of the list (this is done in SWI-Prolog by select/3) and I check if it's in the rest of the list :

```
duplicate(L, V) :-
    select(V, L, L1),
    member(V, L1).
```

Comment: Replace `Id1 \= Id2` by `Id1 < Id2` to avoid a redundant answer.

Comment: Of course, `nth` is a `member` that additionally gives the index of the element...

Answer (score 3):

And here the obvious version using grammars. In a sense, we are describing the structure of a list containing a duplicate. That structure is as follows:

- First, there is anything (`...`),
- then there is the element (`[V]`),
- again anything (`...`)
- and again the element (`[V]`)
- followed by anything.

```
duplicate(L, V) :-
   phrase(( ..., [V], ..., [V], ... ), L).

... --> [] | [_], ... .
```

As a downside, this version will produce redundant answers for a query like

```
?- duplicate([a,a,a],a).
```

This can be overcome by using `dif/2`:

```
duplicate(L, V) :-
   phrase(( all(dif(V)), [V], all(dif(V)), [V], ... ), L).
```

The definition for non-terminal [`all//1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971037/prolog-removing-unique-elements-only/21994498#21994498).

Answer (score 3):

**[Pure](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/logical-purity/info)** and simple! Use [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`tcount/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29960878/4609915) with reified term equality [`(=)/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915) like so:

```
?- tcount(=(X), [1,2,3,4,1], 2).
X = 1 ;                              % succeeds, but leaves choicepoint
false.

?- tcount(=(1), [1,2,3,4,1], 2).
true.                                % succeeds deterministically

?- tcount(=(X), [b,c,d,a,b,a,c], 2).
X = b ;
X = c ;
X = a ;
false.

?- tcount(=(a), [b,c,d,a,b,a,c], 2).   
true.                                % succeeds deterministically
```

Last, let's run the following quite general query:

```
?- tcount(=(a), Ls, 2).
Ls = [a,a]                                           ;
Ls = [a,a,_X],       dif(_X,a)                       ;
Ls = [a,a,_X,_Y],    dif(_X,a), dif(_Y,a)            ;
Ls = [a,a,_X,_Y,_Z], dif(_X,a), dif(_Y,a), dif(_Z,a) ...
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution by @false is as clean as it will get. Here is a more verbose solution that states the problem in simpler terms. One thing to remember is that a "duplicated" element might mean that an element occurs exactly twice -- this is how this predicate interprets it -- or it might mean that an element occurs more than once -- this is what you probably mean (so the name `duplicate` is in fact misleading)

```
%% duplicate(List, Element) is true for every matching pair of _Element_ in _List_
duplicate([First|Rest], Element) :-
    duplicate_1(Rest, First, Element).

% First occurrence
duplicate_1([This|Rest], X, X) :- % first occurrence
    duplicate_2(Rest, This, X).
duplicate_1([This|Rest], _, X) :- % look further for first occurrence
    duplicate_1(Rest, This, X).

% Second occurrence
duplicate_2(_, X, X). % second occurrence
duplicate_2([This|Rest], _, X) :- % look further for second occurrence
    duplicate_2(Rest, This, X).
```

This can now be used in all directions:

```
?- duplicate([b,c,d,a,b,a,c], X).
X = b ;
X = c ;
X = a ;
false.

?- duplicate([b,c,d,a,b,a,c], a).
true ;
false.

?- duplicate(L, a).
L = [a, a|_G274] ;
L = [a, _G273, a|_G277] ;
L = [a, _G273, _G276, a|_G280] .
```

You will have to use cuts, or `dif/2`, or `once/1` to get rid of the multiple answers, if they are a problem. How exactly depends on how you want to use the predicate.

Answer (score 0):

for the first part of your problem I have found a simple solution:

```
duplicated([H|T], Item) :- H == Item, second_stage(T, Item).  %first occurence found
duplicated([H|T], Item) :- duplicated(T, Item).
second_stage([H|T], Item) :- H == Item.   %second occurence found -> match!
second_stage([H|T], Item) :- second_stage(T, Item).
```

This will give true f.e. with duplicated([1,2,3,1,5], 1).

For the second part (query with Variable) I will try to find a way...but I dont
know if this is possible in Prolog.

:)