# Number of occurrences of X in the List L in prolog

Tags: prolog

I am trying to find the number of occurrences of X in the List L
For eg :-

```
occurrences(a, [b, a, b, c, a, d, a], N ).
N =3
```

My code not working .Here is my code.

```
occ(K,L,N) :-  N1=0,  occ1(K,L,N1,N).

occ1(K,[],N1,N) :- N=N1.
occ1(K,L,N1,N) :-
   L=[X|L1], 
   ( K=X -> N1 is N1+1, occ1(K,L1,N1,N) ; occ1(K,L1,N1,N) ).
```

Can anybody tell me what's wrong in the code.

Answer (score 2):

While the answer given by @Kay is spot-on as far as fixing the bug is concerned, it completely circumvents a much bigger issue: The code of `occ1/4` is *logically impure*.

This may not appear very important to you right now, 
but using impure code has several negative consequences:

1. Impure code cannot be read declaratively, only procedurally.
2. Debugging impure code is often tedious and pain-staking.
3. Impure predicates are less "relational" than their pure counterparts.
4. Logical impurity hampers code re-use.
5. Because it is non-monotone, impure code is prone to lead to logically unsound answers, particularly when working with non-ground terms.

To show that these problems persisted in your code after having been "fixed" as suggested @Kay, let us consider the "corrected" code and some queries. First, here's the corrected code:

```
occ(K,L,N) :-  N1=0,  occ1(K,L,N1,N).

occ1(_,[],N1,N) :- N=N1.
occ1(K,L,N1,N) :-
   L=[X|L1], 
   ( K=X -> N2 is N1+1, occ1(K,L1,N2,N) ; occ1(K,L1,N1,N) ).
```

Here's the query you gave in your question:

```
?- occ(a,[b,a,b,c,a,d,a],N).
N = 3 ;
false.
```

Okay! What if we write the query differently?

```
?- A=a,B=b,C=c,D=d, occ(a,[B,A,B,C,A,D,A],N).
A = a, B = b, C = c, D = d, N = 3 ;
false.
```

Okay! What if we reorder goals? Logical conjunction *should* be commutative...

```
?- occ(a,[B,A,B,C,A,D,A],N), A=a,B=b,C=c,D=d.
false.
```

**Fail!** It **seemed** that `occ1/4` is fine, but now we get an answer that is logically unsound.

This can be avoided by using **logically pure** code:
Look at the pure and **monotone** code I gave in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29960878/4609915) to the related question "[Prolog - count repititions in list (sic)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20484180/prolog-count-repititions-in-list)".

Answer (score 1):

The problem is

```
N1 is N1+1
```

Variables cannot be "overwritten" in Prolog. You need to just a new variable, e.g.

```
N2 is N1+1, occ1(K,L1,N2,N)
```

---

To your question "Can we replace a particular list element. If yes, what is the syntax?":

You can only build a new list:

```
replace(_, _, [], []).
replace(Old, New, [H0|T0], [H1|T1]) :-
    (H0 = Old -> H1 = New; H1 = H0),
    replace(Old, New, T0, T1).
```

Comment: Can we replace a particular list element. If yes, what is the syntex. Thanks