# Prolog Length of Evens in a List

Tags: list, recursion, prolog, sublist, variable-length

I am a Prolog beginner, and I have the following length function:

```html
mylen([H|Lc],N) :- mylen(Lc,M),N is M+1.
mylen([],0).
```

I would like to know if there's an easy way to query the interpreter to calculate the length of the list of evens in a list, and if not, how I would go about incrementing N only on an even number. Thanks.

Comment: Wow. [*Deja vu*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28785391/just-started-on-prolog-please-show-me-how-to-counting-even-number-in-a-list). (See the link)

Comment: I voted to close as a duplicate, following @lurker's observation of a glitch in the matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something similar to this is what you might be looking for

```
mylen([H|Lc],N) :- 
X is mod(H,2),
X == 0,
mylen(Lc,M),
N is M+1.

mylen([],0).

mylen([H|Lc],N) :-
mylen(Lc, M),
N = M.
```

Comment: Run `mylen([1,2,3,4,5], N).` How many solutions does it give? Are they all correct? How many should there be?