# Prolog: Count positive elems in list

Tags: list, prolog, clpfd, visual-prolog

i want to count positive elements in list (VIsual Prolog). So i wrote this function:

```
positiveCount([], C).
positiveCount([A], C) :- A > 0, C = C + 1.
positiveCount([H|T], C) :- H > 0,!,C = C+1,positiveCount(T,C); positiveCount(T,C).
```

Error:

```
The flow pattern '(o,i)' does not exist for '+' main.pro
```

AS i understood from this error, i can't use `C=C+1` for C as input variable.

Any ideas how can i fix my code?

Comment: First, you need to realize that, as a logical statement, `C = C + 1` does not make much sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code uses [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) on [swi-prolog](/questions/tagged/swi-prolog), so don't expect it to run *as-is* on [visual-prolog](/questions/tagged/visual-prolog):-(
 Still, I hope it is of use to you!

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

count_pos([], 0).
count_pos([E|Es], C) :- E #=< 0,            count_pos(Es, C).
count_pos([E|Es], C) :- E #>  0, C #= C0+1, count_pos(Es, C0).
```

Let's read the clauses in plain English **in** the direction of the "arrow" `:-`, that is "right to left".

1. `count_pos([], 0).`

   > The number of positive arithmetic expressions contained in the empty list `[]` is zero.
2. `count_pos([E|Es], C) :- E #=< 0, count_pos(Es, C).`

   > *If* list `Es` contains `C` positive arithmetic expressions
   >  *and if* some arithmetic expression `E` is not positive
   >  *then* conclude that `[E|Es]` also contains `C` positive arithmetic expressions.
3. `count_pos([E|Es], C) :- E #> 0, C #= C0+1, count_pos(Es, C0).`

   > *If* list `Es` contains `C0` positive arithmetic expressions
   >  *and if* some arithmetic expression `E` *is* positive 
   >  *then* conclude that `[E|Es]` also contains `C0+1` positive arithmetic expressions.

Sample query:

```
?- count_pos([1,2,3,0,-1,-2], C).
   C = 3
;  false.
```

Comment: I find it extremely valuable that you are posting such declarative solutions, thank you! It may seem repetitive, but on the other hand, contrast a few dozen posts with the vast amount of Prolog teaching material that does not contain a single grain of such methods, and from that see how much more is needed to provide the first traces of counterweight to the hitherto accumulated garbage!

Comment: @mat. Thank you! I really appreciate it. Always focus on what we can do... bottom line: "I suggest that you deal with the issue on a going forward basis." http://dilbert.com/strip/1998-02-09

Comment: Does this work with [`tcount/3`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29960878/772868), too?