# Count specific element in list [Prolog]

Tags: prolog

I want to count a specific element in a list.

```
?count(3,[3,3,3],C).

count(_,[],_).
count(X,[Y|R],C):- X \= Y, count(X,R,C).
count(X,[Y|R],C):- X = Y, L is C + 1, count(X,R,L).
```

But I get this error and I do not see why:
Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
In:
[1] count(3,[3,3|...],_1594)

Do you have a tipp?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29960878/772868) is a pure version.

Comment: fix: `count(_,[],0).` and `:- X = Y, count(X,R,L), C is L + 1.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instantiation error occurs in the goal `L is C + 1` as the variable `C` is unbound when the goal is called.

One solution is to rewrite the predicate to use an *accumulator*. Doing the minimal changes to your code:

```
count(Element, List, Count) :-
    count(Element, List, 0, Count).

count(_, [], Count, Count).
count(X, [Y|R], Count0, Count) :-
    X \= Y,
    count(X, R, Count0, Count).
count(X, [Y|R], Count0, Count) :-
    X = Y,
    Count1 is Count0 + 1,
    count(X, R, Count1, Count).
```

With your sample call:

```
| ?- count(3, [3,3,3], Count).

Count = 3 ? ;

no
```

Notice that this new definition leaves a spurious *choice-point*. Can you improve it so that calls (with the two first arguments ground) become deterministic? Hint: start by moving the list argument to the first position in the auxiliary `count/4` predicate.